How to fix damaged garage door?
I managed to break the inside garage wall panel. It looks like there is a styrofoam inside the panel. The outer layer that encapsulates the styrofoam is made up of thin plastic kind of material.
Any idea how to fix this? If I can not fix this, what am I replacing? Just the insulation part or entire panel?


The degree to which a fix is made depends on your desire for aesthetics.
The damage is only to the interior skin covering and the styrofoam insulation. This is there for insulation and reduction of heat/cold transfer from the exterior metal skin of the door.  There is no effect to the operation of the door.
You can smooth out the plastic a bit and tape the edges with an aluminium tape and the area will be fully functional.  If you can find some white duct or packaging tape it will be far less noticeable.
If you want a repair that is totally unnoticeable, find the manufacturer of the door and order a new insulation panel and cover.

Upvoted, but not sure about last paragraph. Can you really procure and replace just the inside or innards of a door panel?    If not, and you buy the whole panel, it's not a DIY job for most people.

@jay613 doesn't seem that difficult, but I guess this guy is a pro? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV980cmEz8E

@Huesmann yes, that's a video showing a pro making no mistakes, replacing a door that's in perfect shape, with a technique that works for the middle panels only, and omitting all issues of safety.

@jay613, the insulation panels can be replaced. They are usually just stuck on with a few wads of glue.  There are some that are available to insulate a non insulated door. It is easier than installing a shower rod.
